# Redirect headers with Phonegap

Tags: php, cordova, laravel, phonegap-cli

When attempting to send a post request to http://med.app/tour/pull (a laravel route) as an attempt to pull data from the server; my application then realises the user is not authenticated so it redirects them to another page.

[image]

Because the application is under the Phonegap serve proxy; It becomes confused and appears as 'http://undefined/proxy/http://med.apphttp://med.app/login' instead of redirecting it to http://med.app/login.

For reference; the Laravel code causing the redirect is the following in `Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

What solution would be the best for this issue? Is this something I should resolve on Laravel or with Phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is unauthorised then server should just response with 401 status code and at phonegap end you should write your code as it detects 401 status code and then redirect to login.
In web api there should be no redirection, only JSON response.